# I am using Django 1.8(django-registration-redux==1.8) and keep getting redirected to /profile when trying to get to my registrations page

Tags: django, django-registration

I would like to be able to get to the registration page so that I can login.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in bookstore.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^store/
^accounts/ ^activate/complete/$ [name='registration_activation_complete']
^accounts/ ^activate/resend/$ [name='registration_resend_activation']
^accounts/ ^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='registration_activate']
^accounts/ ^register/complete/$ [name='registration_complete']
^accounts/ ^register/closed/$ [name='registration_disallowed']
^accounts/ ^register/$ [name='registration_register']
^accounts/ ^login/$ [name='auth_login']
^accounts/ ^logout/$ [name='auth_logout']
^accounts/ ^password/change/$ [name='auth_password_change']
^accounts/ ^password/change/done/$ [name='auth_password_change_done']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/$ [name='auth_password_reset']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/complete/$ [name='auth_password_reset_complete']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='auth_password_reset_done']
^accounts/ ^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$ [name='auth_password_reset_confirm']
^admin/
The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store/', include('store.urls'), name='store'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]
```

Above is what my urls.py in my base applicaiton looks like. I tried using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py but still was not able to get to the registration page I want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)? In your post you put `redirect_url`.

Comment: Sorry. That's what I meant.

Comment: Consider editing your question to change that bit, also show what your conf of the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is.